# How to change Twitch stream title via node.js?

Tags: node.js, axios, twitch, twitch-api

I'm attempting to change the stream title using the Twitch API and I'm getting a 404 error.  I referred to the docs [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#modify-channel-information) and followed its example but no luck.

```
var axios = require('axios');

headers = {
    'Authorization':'Bearer [token]',
    'Client-Id':'[client id]',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
}

data = {
    'title':'changed title'
}

axios.post('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channels?broadcaster_id=[broadcaster id]', data, {'headers':headers}).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data);
}).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I learnt 2 things:

1. the API documentation said the method should be PATCH, not POST.  So it should be `axios.patch`, not `axios.post`
2. the broadcaster ID must match the Authorization token + client ID (I'm using two different accounts for streaming and the twitch chat bot)